# Handling embedded videos in excerpts

Tags: multisite, excerpt

Background: I have a multisite install, where users have their own blogs. I'm working on a page for the main site which will list the most recently updated blogs and excerpts from the first three (WIP version here: http://threemix.co.uk/blog-network/ )

One of my users runs a video blog. Unfortunately, this messes up the excerpts when his is one of the most recent three updated blogs: more specifically, neither the excerpt nor a link to the post show (his blog is  "Greg Does Reading" on the link above).

```
<section class="network-posts">
    <?php
    $thisblogid = get_current_blog_id();
    $blogs = get_last_updated('', 1, 12);
    $blogno = 1; 

    foreach ($blogs as $blog) : 
        switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']); 
        global $post; 
        $myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts'=>1)); 
    ?>

    <?php if ($blogno == 1) { ?>
        <ul class="fresh">
    <?php } if ($blogno >= 1 && $blogno <= 3) { ?>
        <li class="fresh col-<?php echo (($blogno % 3)); ?> <?php if (count($myposts) == 0) : echo('no-posts'); endif;?>">
        <section><hgroup>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><h2><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></h2></a>
        </hgroup>

        <ul>
        <?php $i = 0; foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br/>
            <?php echo get_my_excerpt(15); ?>  
            </li>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        </section></li>
    <?php } if ($blogno == 3) { ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } if ($blogno > 3) { 
        // if not one of the first three posts ?>
            //ommitted for brevity        

    <?php } $blogno++?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php switch_to_blog($thisblogid) ; ?>

</section>
```

The first three posts are generated in the inner  tags. I am switching to each blog in order, taking the $post object of the most recent post, and using it in a custom loop.

Two questions:

1. Why is the post's title not showing up? I can understand why the
   excerpt isn't, but not the post title.
2. How can I change my
   get_my_excerpt() function (which at the moment, just changes the
   length of the excerpt), to include embedded YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $wp_embed;
if ( get_option('embed_autourls') )
    remove_filter('the_content',array(&$wp_embed,'autoembed'));

// do excerpt/content stuff

if ( get_option('embed_autourls') )
    add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$wp_embed, 'autoembed'), 8 );
```